# Custom property for RemoveExistingProducts action

Tags: installation, windows-installer, upgrade

When the `RemoveExistingProducts` action is executed, the MSI sets two properties

- UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE={...}
- REMOVE=ALL

How to add a custom property for this action?

Comment: I don't understand your question or what you're trying to accomplish. Can you please clarify your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RemoveExistingProducts` is a built-in installer command, you cannot change it.

If you want to do something after this, you have to look for all places it is called (probably in InstallExecuteSequence) and call your Custom Action, set a property, or whatever after it.